# What is the AZ CLI equivalent of Get-AzSqlServerThreatDetectionPolicy?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to port some old Azure PowerShell code to the new AZ CLI. While I can check the threat detection policies on databases using "az sql db threat-policy" I cannot find the equivalent for the server itself.

I would have expected it at "az sql server threat-policy" but that doesn't exist. Does anyone know the AZ CLI equivalent to Get-AzSqlServerThreatDetectionPolicy?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure there is none: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server?view=azure-cli-latest

Which is nothing unheard of, different tools in azure have slightly different capabilities